# Storing array data from angularjs Form using MEAN stack

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I am using [MEAN](http://meanjs.org) stack. while creating a new article i would like to save array data. below code has the section `deal` which needs to be an array of data, for which i am unable to store array data. how do i modify my html partial and angularJS Controller so that i can store data like below for `deal`

```
{
"_id": "565d8a3a0ede9823aca797e9",
"user": {
"_id": "564ef3eaebf280b0abcc4876",
"displayName": "Table 2"
},
"__v": 0,
"deal": ["Special","Holiday"],
"name": "Idli",
"created": "2015-12-01T11:53:30.759Z"
}
```

My NodeJS Server Model

```
var FoodSchema = new Schema({
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Food name',
    trim: true
  },
  deal: [{
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
  }],
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

my AngularJS controller

```
$scope.create = function (isValid) {
  $scope.error = null;

  if (!isValid) {
    $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'foodForm');

    return false;
  }

  // Create new Food object
  var food = new Foods({
    name: this.name,
    deal: this.deal,

  // Redirect after save
  food.$save(function (response) {
    $location.path('foods/' + response._id);

    // Clear form fields
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.deal = '';
  }, function (errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
  });
};
```

HTML Partial

```
<section ng-controller="FoodsController">
<div layout="row" layout-wrap class="create-food">

    <form name="foodForm" ng-submit="create(foodForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <md-input-container flex="">
            <label >Food Name</label>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name"  required>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6">

    <md-input-container class="">
    <label class="" for="deal">Deal</label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="deal" id="deal"   required>
</md-input-container>
</div>
<md-button type="submit">Create Food</md-button>

</form>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store data on your browser you can use the new html5 feature localStorage(key,value) you put some key for getting and the json like value.

This is not just for the sesion !

Comment: i would like to store it in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see that you already updated your mongoose model schema and made some updates in the frontend but what's the current state of your server API? Do you have any endpoints defined for the requests?

In other words (using the articles example of MEAN.js):

```
var articlesPolicy = require('../policies/articles.server.policy'),
    articles = require('../controllers/articles.server.controller');

module.exports = function (app) {
    // Articles collection routes
    app.route('/api/articles').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
        .get(articles.list)
        .post(articles.create);

    // Single article routes
    app.route('/api/articles/:articleId').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
        .get(articles.read)
        .put(articles.update)
        .delete(articles.delete);

    // Finish by binding the article middleware
    app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);
};
```

Do you already have a similar setup for Food?

Once you have your routes setup you should then verify the server controllers logic and see if the data is being handled correctly and save into mongodb.

**Edit to explain the workflow of saving data to mongodb in MEAN.js:**

The database is only accessible from the server for security reasons. You cant access mongodb directly from angularjs. The process is: angular passes the data to expressjs via a request (for example: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Then in the server you should be able to capture the requests by defining your route endpoints. In those route endpoints you can specify route middlewares (i.e., server controllers) that will then use mongoose to interact with mongodb.

Comment: Yes my route is like this, i tried inserting array data through the terminal, it stored like this `{
"_id": "5677ec1253f11260f5731c7c",
"deal": ["check1","check2"],
"name": "hello",
"created": "2015-12-21T12:11:03.551Z"
}`. backend is working. how do i store it so using AngularJS. Thank you

Comment: I think you're mistaking some concepts within MEAN.js, check my updated answer